# How to center columns in DT package? R

Tags: r, dt

```
datatable(head(iris))
```

[image]

How can I center my columns so they're right underneath my column names?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `columnDefs` argument argument under `options`.  Set `className` to `dt-center` to center columns and use `targets` to set which columns you'd like to center, for example as a range, `0:4` (starts at zero), or `_all` for all of them.

```
library(DT)
datatable(head(iris),
          options = list(columnDefs = 
                           list(list(className = 'dt-center', 
                                     targets = "_all"))))
```

[image]